# Difference between GDAS and GFS data

Tags: meteorology, models, weather-forecasting, gfs

What is the exact difference between GFS 0.25 and GDAS 0.25 data which is available in http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/.

And are the GFS 0.5 and 1 degree data available in the above url and [here](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/model-data/model-datasets/global-forcast-system-gfs) the same?